# Java Mockito useConstructor withSettings, error Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to Mock this following code with transaction manager. Receiving error below. How can I resolve this?

**Code:**

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition paramTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());
TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(paramTransactionDefinition);
```

**Test:**

```
@Mock
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Mock
private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;
@Mock
private DataSource dataSource;
@Mock
private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;

given(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate()).willAnswer(a -> jdbcTemplate);
given(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource()).willAnswer(a -> dataSource);
platformTransactionManager = Mockito.mock(DataSourceTransactionManager.class, withSettings().useConstructor(dataSource));

given(platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(any())).willAnswer(a -> transactionStatus);
```

**Error:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at         given(platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(any())).willAnswer(a -> transactionStatus);


This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
```

trying to use this resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60429929/15435022

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'dataSource' is required Error in java (Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671627/property-datasource-is-required-error-in-java-spring)

Comment: the code works in production, just the actual unit test @Pirate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
@Mock
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Mock
private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;
@Mock
private DataSource dataSource;
@Mock
private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;

given(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate()).willAnswer(a -> jdbcTemplate);
given(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource()).willAnswer(a -> dataSource);

MockedConstruction<DataSourceTransactionManager> mocked = Mockito.mockConstruction(DataSourceTransactionManager.class,
        (mock, context) -> {
            when(mock.getTransaction(any())).thenReturn(null);
        });
given(platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition())).willAnswer(a -> transactionStatus);
mocked.close();
```

**Resource:** https://rieckpil.de/mock-java-constructors-and-their-object-creation-with-mockito/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking things a bit too eagerly while mocking.
Given should look like this:

```java
//method with parameter
given(aMock.aSingleCall(anArgumentMatcher)).willReturn(aValue);
//method without parameter
given(aMock.aSingleCall()).willReturn(aValue);
```

The chained call you are using here:

```java
given(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource()).willAnswer(a -> dataSource);
```

Is supposed to be split into two pieces, like this:

```java
given(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate()).willReturn(jdbcTemplate);
given(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).willReturn(dataSource);
```

On the constructor call, you are facing the issue of not actually using the mock while stubbing. Mockito will not be able to magically replace your constructor call with a mocking (and it shouldn't either). You should be simply using something like one of the following scenarios.

**A) If you want to mock only the `dataSource`**

Change your code in a way you can set the `dataSource` mock you have like this:

```java
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
```

It can be through a constructor or setter, does not matter.

**B) If you want to mock the `transactionManager` as well**

Change your code to avoid directly calling the constructor, accept the `transactionManager` as a dependency and set the mock you have already created (the field named `platformTransactionManager`).

**Note:** Calling `any(aClass)` will return the default value of the type when the `any(aClass)` is executed. In your case, this is a `null` so when you are calling the real constructor with it, you are just writing `new DataSourceTransactionManager(null)` with extra steps.

**Update#1: how do I "Change your code in a way"?**

It depends on the rest of your code, but assuming that this is in a single method:

```java
DefaultTransactionDefinition paramTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());
TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(paramTransactionDefinition);
```

you could either use a parameter of `PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager` and avoid the constructor call (extract parameter) or you could at least extract the constructor call to a method and you can use a Mockito spy to make that method return a mock instead of the real object.

Comment: how do I "Change your code in a way"?

Comment: I am trying to use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60429929/15435022

Comment: A good example for how you can extract a method and avoid the constructor call can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265465/17174122